# while (left button pressed) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mouseevent, matlab-figure

I've written a program in Matlab which draws a figure. I want to activate it in a while loop when left mouse button is pressed.
How can I do this?

I've used "waitforbuttonpress", but it works once. I want continuous preformance.

```
while (?)

functionA(); % draws a figure with get(0, 'PointerLocation') as input. 

drawnow;
cla;
end
```

a figure updates with mouse movement only when left mouse button is pressed.

Comment: Are you using "old" Figures, or UIFigures? Also, which version of MATLAB is this?

Comment: I was using old ones. Matlab 2018b.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am understanding well, but if you want your loop to run continuously, you could change the while condition:

```
while (1)
    if ~waitforbuttonpress
        functionA(); % draws a figure with get(0, 'PointerLocation') as input. 
        drawnow;
        cla;
    end
end
```

Then you can insert a break condition in the while (1) loop, such as:

```
while (1)
        if input('Exit loop?') %%exit if keyboard value is different from 0
            break;
        end
end
```

Comment: "if ~waitforbuttonpress" doesn't work continuously. it is like taking snapshots...

Comment: then maybe you should look at some examples of callbacks:
https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7301-gui-examples-using-nested-functions
https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/52816-how-detect-the-mouse-press-of-a-pushbutton
I think that editing the callback function of WindowButtonDownFcn and of WindowButtonUpFcn you can track when you press and release the button